# UIView not transparent to all views underneath

Tags: ios, uiview, transparency, alpha

I am working on an iOS application and I am having the following problem: I have a `UIView` which background color has `alpha = 0.8`, but I do not want it to be see-through for all elements underneath it. I am making it transparent by adding the following code to its `Draw(CGRect rect)` method:

```
var gctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
gctx.AddEllipseInRect(new CGRect(rect.Location, rect.Size));
gctx.SetFillColor(UIColor.FromRGB(255, 255, 255).ColorWithAlpha(0.8f).CGColor);
```

However, in this way it is see-through for all of the `UIViews` underneath it. The following image is illustrating what I mean:

[image]

The big circle has `alpha = 0.8`, while the small one, which is below it, has `alpha = 1`. What I want to achieve is the part of the small circle that is behind the big one to be invisible, while the big circle has `alpha = 0.2` in order to be slightly transparent to the background gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use gc clip feature for small circle.
You need to set big circle or inverse of it as clip path and draw the circle.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClip