# Make UIView Transparent to Only Certain Views

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics, transparency

I currently have a UIView, which is completely transparent and put above many other labels. There is a background image behind all the labels, and, since all labels are transparent-backgrounded, I can see through them to see the picture. Then, as this view placed on top of labels is also set to transparent, I can see the labels behind it. Is there a way to make this view only transparent to the background image? That it, when I see through it, I ONLY see the background image and not the labels, as if the labels don't exist under this view.

P.S. I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322095/uiview-not-transparent-to-all-views-underneath) which is definitely related, but the link in the answer is dead.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This is what I mean:

[image]

The transparent view that the arrow is pointing to, is NOT in the scroll view, but hovering above it. There will be a lot of text content in the scrollview, and therefore when they pass under the pointed view, they will be visible. How do I make this hovering view reflect only the big imageview behind it, and not any text behind it? That is, I want that when texts pass under this view, they are invisible, and the view always reflects the background image. And, as it's an always-changing image and not a solid color, I cannot just set the color of this hovering view to match the background.

Comment: if you want the label to disappear, hide the label, whenever you wanted. Please clarify if i missed anything.

Comment: If all the labels are added to a view and this view is transparent placed above background image view, then you can easily show hide this view whenever required, similar to Ratul's comment, but with a container view for all labels

Comment: Please see the updated question @RatulSharker

Comment: Please see the updated question @AnnieDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get your question, but I will give you a solution the link you have provided.

So in the link, we have a big transparent circle and we wish to block the small circle in the background right.

What you can is this.

You create two identical views.

First view is your normal view, you display whatever you want on it. The second you will be a backgroundView which is of the same position and same size as the first view. But the catch is this, the backgroundView will be displaying the same background color as the real background view.

So the view hierarchy will be like this

1. Display View (Circle shape)
2. BackgroundView (Circle size, same position as first view, same color as real background view, in this case color Blue)
3. Real BackgroundView (Color blue ).

then all you have to do is keep the alpha value of the backgroundView as 1 and change the alpha value of the first view to, let's say, 0.6

sample code

```
 private func addCircle(){
    // adding a blue circle
    let circleView = UIView()
    circleView.backgroundColor = .blue
    circleView.alpha = 0.5

    view.addSubview(circleView)

    circleView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    circleView.center = view.center
    circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 100 / 2
    circleView.layer.masksToBounds = true


    // adding a backgroundView
    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = .red
    view.insertSubview(backgroundView, belowSubview: circleView)

    backgroundView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    backgroundView.center = view.center
    backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 100 / 2
    backgroundView.layer.masksToBounds = true


}
```

Comment: You can also create a custom View with two layers. It will be alot cleaner and it will be using less memory. But what I have given you is a straightforward and easy to understand solution.

Comment: Please see the updated question. It's a background image. @programmingBeginner

Comment: @Edward then you do the same? Just make the backgroundView a view with image but without the labels you were talking about? If you need scrolling, then the background view will be a scrollView with the image but moves together with the top scrollView

Comment: The problem is - a part of the image. The image has to look continuous, and it's hard to crop it just in place

Comment: @Edward Does the background image scroll with the scrollview?

Comment: No, and that's where problems arise. Whatever when scrolled under that hovering view is blocked, and when scrolled out, is visible again. @programmingBeginner

Comment: @Edward "Whatever when scrolled under that hovering view is blocked, and when scrolled out, is visible again" this is what you want, or what you don want?

Comment: Exactly what I want @programmingBeginner

Comment: @Edward If that is the case, I believe I have answered? So let me repeat: First, you create a view (we call it middleView) that is of same size and frame of your hovering view to put in between the hovering view and the scrollView. 2. Add an imageView (or layer if you know how to manipulate layer) in the middleView. 3. set the image in the imageView. 4. Set the clipsToBounds property of middleView to true. 5. Adjust the imageView position in the middleView, so it looks continuous with the backgroundImageView.